# Как организовать парсинг с авторизацией на Python?

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, никак не работает парсинг с авторизацией, посмотрел все видео, правда их там не так много, ничего не помогает? Просто каждый раз отдает мне код страницы с авторизацией.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent

session = requests.Session()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user.random
}

data = {
    "username": "//////",
    "password": "//////"
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Вангую, что в заголовках или куках response авторизации есть какой-то ключ который нужно добавить к соответствующим данным сессии

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду записать еще что-то в словарь?

Comment: Если да, то дело не в этом

Comment: Нууу... не совсем. Ваш "словарь" ни к кукам ни к заголовкам отношения не имеет

Comment: в переменной data нет ключа 'logintoken' значение которого можно найти в html страницы.